# Inverse Column and row header in handsontable

Tags: jquery, html, handsontable

Normally [HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/) having A,B,C.. in column header and 1,2,3.. in row header.

I want to inverse it.  ie, A,B,C.. for row header and 1,2,3.. for column header.

thanks
Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

You can render custom row/column headers. The following code fragment is from the documentation. You may prepare a proper array with your headers and then pass it to the colHeaders / rowHeaders:

```
$container.handsontable({
  colHeaders: [
    "<b>Bold</b> and <em>Beautiful</em>",
    "Some <input type='checkbox' class='checker'> checkbox"
  ]
});
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers_html.html#header